# Start/stop Tomcat from Ant - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, build

I am trying to start/stop tomcat from Ant. Here is my relevant portion of the xml file for stopping :

```
<target name="stop" depends="readProperties" >
    <exec executable="/home/local/WorkEnvironment/apache-tomcat-7.0.14/bin/">
        <arg value="shutdown.sh"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

This gives the following exception :

```
/home/local/workspace/Eclipse/Main/tomcat.xml:26: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
   at java.lang.PosixProcess.<init>(libgcj.so.11)
   at java.lang.Runtime.execInternal(libgcj.so.11)
   at java.lang.Runtime.exec(libgcj.so.11)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:862)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:495)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:631)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.11)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
   at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
   at java.lang.PosixProcess.nativeSpawn(libgcj.so.11)
   at java.lang.PosixProcess.spawn(libgcj.so.11)
   at java.lang.PosixProcess$ProcessManager.run(libgcj.so.11)
```

Seeing this, I tried the following :

```
<target name="stop" depends="readProperties" >
    <echo message="${tomcat.path.home}"/>

    <java jar="${tomcat.path.home}/bin/bootstrap.jar" fork="true">
           <jvmarg value="-Dcatalina.home=${tomcat.path.home}"/>

            <arg line="stop"></arg>
    </java>
</target>
```

This tells me that :

```
stop:
     [echo] /home/local/WorkEnvironment/apache-tomcat-7.0.14
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
     [java]    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:60)
     [java]    at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.11)
     [java] Java Result: 1
```

I checked for tomcat-juli.jar and its present in tomcat_home/bin and also in tomcat_home/lib. It also has the class which  ant says is missing. What is going wrong ? I saw that sometimes the Manifest.MF file can mislead, but, I could not make out what exactly could be wrong with that file :( .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't executable include "shutdown.sh"? (not shutdown as an arg, but as part of the executable path).

Something like:

```
<target name="stop" depends="readProperties" >
    <exec executable="/home/local/WorkEnvironment/apache-tomcat-7.0.14/bin/shutdown.sh">
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks ! That worked. I was googling around and I saw that it was passed as an argument. My bad. Thanks !